# Why Math.Round doesn't always rounding doubles

Tags: c#, math, double, decimal

```
int fieldGoals =                int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int fieldGoalAttempts =         int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int threePointFieldGoals =      int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int turnovers =                 int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int offensiveRebounds =         int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int opponentDefensiveRebounds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int freeThrows =                int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int freeThrowAttempts =         int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double eFG = Math.Round( (fieldGoals + 0.5 * threePointFieldGoals) / fieldGoalAttempts );
double TOV = Math.Round( turnovers / (fieldGoalAttempts + 0.44 * freeThrowAttempts + turnovers) );
double ORB = Math.Round( offensiveRebounds / (offensiveRebounds + opponentDefensiveRebounds) );
double FT  = Math.Round( freeThrows / fieldGoalAttempts );
```

The problem is with `double ORB` and `double FT`.

For some reason I can't use `Math.Round` on them. It says  that:

> the call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties :
>   "Math.Round(double)" and  "Math.Round(decimal)".

I just don't get it why the first two work but the second two don't.

Comment: Declare all your `int` variables as `double`, that seems to be the best option in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first two calls, you added something to both. `0.5` and `0.44` both convert the values to doubles, because `0.5` and `0.44` are both considered doubles. But when you use the second two, they are both only using integers, which are neither double nor decimal, and which can be converted to either. To solve this you simply need to do `Math.Round( (double) (*calculations*) );`

Alternatively, and in fact the better way to do it would be to convert *one* of the values to double - that way, it would calculate the division in double.
`(double)offensiveRebounds / (offensiveRebounds + opponentDefensiveRebounds)`
`(double)freeThrows / fieldGoalAttempts`

Comment: *they are both only using integers, which are neither double nor decimal, and which can be converted to either* —this is an important point. You explained what is happening exactly: `Math.Round()` has no implementation for an integer argument, but has a `double` and a `decimal` overloads. Which is why there's an ambiguity when passing an integer argument.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Math.Round` with `int` values. You probably want to convert them to `double` first:`Math.Round( 1.0 * freeThrows...)`.

There is no `Math.Round(int)` overloaod, but there are overloads for `double` and `decimal` and `int` can be imlicitely converted to both. Therefore the call would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You try to devide integer numbers - the result will be integer. So, you cant round this number. Convert it to double before devision and rounding:

```
double ORB = Math.Round( (double)offensiveRebounds / (offensiveRebounds + opponentDefensiveRebounds) );
double FT  = Math.Round( (double)freeThrows / fieldGoalAttempts );
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I see why the first two work and the others don't. Thank you again.

Comment: @IvailoKorakov glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

In the first two you have implicitly converted the argument to Math.Round to a double with the double (i.e. 0.5 and 0.44) used as the multiplication factor.

In the second two, you have not.